# Extracting values with if and put them in a new column

Tags: r, if-statement

maybe this is a very simple question, but I cannot figure out what is wrong with my short code.

This is my (very simple) data frame:

```
structure(list(sample = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.1446689595, 
0.9151456018, 0.880888083, 0.005522657, 0.7079621046, 0.4770259836, 
0.6960717649, 0.5892328324, 0.1134234308), new = c("red", "red", 
"red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red")), .Names = c("sample", 
"value", "new"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

what I would like to do is add a new column where the new values depend on the values of the first column. In other and simpler words:

```
if (df1$sample != "a") {
    df1$new <- "green"
} else {
    df1$new <- "red"
}
```

but R returns an error:

```
In if (df1$sample != "a") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I also tried with an `elseif` statement:

```
ifelse(df1$sample != "a", df1$new <- "green", df1$new <- "red")
```

but it this case the `new` column contains only "red" and no "green".

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifelse` should work fine - you just need to assign it

```
df1$new1 <- ifelse(df1$sample != "a", df1$new1 <- "green", df1$new1 <- "red")




  sample       value new  new1
1      a 0.144668959 red   red
2      b 0.915145602 red green
3      a 0.880888083 red   red
4      a 0.005522657 red   red
5      a 0.707962105 red   red
6      b 0.477025984 red green
7      c 0.696071765 red green
8      c 0.589232832 red green
9      c 0.113423431 red green
```

I would avoid using `new` as a variable name - it is the name of a function and this may cause issues.

Comment: thanks for your super fast reply. So what I missed is to specify `df1$new` before `elseif` right?!

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
 df1$new <-  c('green', 'red')[(df1$sample=='a')+1L]
 df1
 #  sample       value   new
 #1      a 0.144668959   red
 #2      b 0.915145602 green
 #3      a 0.880888083   red
 #4      a 0.005522657   red
 #5      a 0.707962105   red
 #6      b 0.477025984 green
 #7      c 0.696071765 green
 #8      c 0.589232832 green
 #9      c 0.113423431 green
```